# Create View vc Create View As Query; What is the difference

Tags: postgresql, ddl, sql-view

I am trying to create a query in Postgresql what when called will get the data at run time from the two tables and hand back to the calling program.   The records need to be updateable so I hope I am doing this correctly.   Where I am having confusion is the difference between:

```
create view workorderquery as SELECT PartsWorkOrder.*, Copiers.*
FROM PartsWorkOrder RIGHT JOIN Copiers ON PartsWorkOrder.Printer = Copiers.Copier as query;
```

and:

```
create view workorderquery as SELECT PartsWorkOrder.*, Copiers.*
FROM PartsWorkOrder RIGHT JOIN Copiers ON PartsWorkOrder.Printer = Copiers.Copier;
```

Do I need the 'as query' at the end?   If so why do I get an error with it?

Comment: The first one is an invalid statement and will not run anyway

Comment: None of them run, no matter what I do the view/query ends up readonly.

Comment: The first one will throw an error (the `as query` at the end is invalid). And of course the second one will be read-only. Only views that select from a single table are automagically updatable [as documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS). For views that use joins you need an [instead of trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)